# Bootstrap 4 перекрывает мои стили

Tags: css3, bootstrap4

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <!-- Иконка -->
   <link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/ico" href = "/www/icon/calendarIcon.ico">
   <title>Планировщик</title>
   <!-- AJAX & jQuery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Подключение моих стилей -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
   <!-- Подключение Bootstrap`a -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Просто текст.
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <?php require_once "server.php" ?>
 </body>
</html>`
```

В script.js у меня ничего нет, как и в server.php, а вот в style.css у меня:
    
     `* {
        color: #05ff00;
       }`
 А вот результат работы:
    [image: Результат работы кода:]

Comment: Порядок подключения стилей важен. Или добавьте `!important` к вашему стилю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключайте свои стили

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

после Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

тогда ваши стили будут перекрывать.

Comment: Все равно не получается. Однако, когда я добавляю `!important`, то все работает. Даже подключать после не нужно, но бесит, ибо после каждого значения писать `!important` такое себе, как мне кажется.